# Cakephp condition not working for enum

Tags: cakephp

I am trying to apply a condition on my company table in cakephp 2.5

I need to select only the companies with status 1, below is the code:

```
$this->loadModel('Company');

$fields=array('id','name','logo','status');

$conditions=array('status'=>'1' );

$search_companies =  $this->Company->find('all',
 array('fields'=>$fields,'conditions'=>$conditions));
```

`this` always returns companies with a status of 0 and not 1 as expected. Why is that?

The database type used for status in my table is enum.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cake does not support `ENUM` out the box, change the data type to `VARCHAR` and it will work.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to change your table schema field to varchar or if it's mysql change to an enum type.
Another solution would be:
`$conditions=array('status=1' );`
if your schema is of type int.